# numpy array is immutable after matplotlib.pyplot.imread()

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Why is the numpy array immutable after being read using matplotlib.pyplot.imread? What is the reasoning behind that?

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> test=matplotlib.pyplot.imread('download.jpeg')
>>> test.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : False
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

Comment: Where is the array?

Comment: @Bazingaa: The array is `test`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of what happens in the code, `matplotlib.pyplot.imread` [delegates to Pillow](https://matplotlib.org/_modules/matplotlib/image.html#imread) to read the file and then [calls `np.asarray`](https://matplotlib.org/_modules/matplotlib/image.html#pil_to_array) on the resulting `PIL.Image.Image` object. When converting a `PIL.Image.Image` to a NumPy array, the Image object [builds a bytestring](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/Image.py#L673) to use as the array's buffer. Bytestrings are immutable, so the resulting array is unwriteable.

In terms of why anyone on the Matplotlib or Pillow dev team chose an implementation that results in an unwriteable array, I don't know. It's not clear whether this was deliberate at all.

If you want a writeable array, call the array's `copy` method:

```
mutable_array = matplotlib.pyplot.imread('download.jpeg').copy()
```